# Android animation in button

Tags: java, android

i am moving my button by animation and button moving visually but when i press the button at new position i don't find it there.

```
final Animation animation1 = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,100);
animation1.setDuration(5000);
animation1.setFillAfter(true);
alphabet.startAnimation(animation1);
humanbody.startAnimation(animation1);
poem.startAnimation(animation1);
game.startAnimation(animation1);
```

When I press alphabet button,it took me to human-body activity And I press somewhere top of alphabet button it took me to alphabet activity

Answer (score 1):

I'm still a beginner at this, but I think that using the `animation` class only animates the `view's` drawable state, not the its bound/touch area.
Try using this:

```
int t = 5000;
int y = 100;
alphabet.animate().setDuration(t).translateY(y).start();
humanbody.animate().setDuration(t).translateY(y).start();
poem.animate().setDuration(t).translateY(y).start();
game.animate().setDuration(t).translateY(y).start();
```

Comment: Thanks. But translateY method shows me error.I used this alphabet.animate().translationY(y).setDuration(t).start(); and it works fine.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry my bad.

Comment: its ok brother.